# Does this clause in my contract bar me from starting my own business?

Tags: employer-relations

Recently, I've been thinking about doing some freelancing and potentially starting a business off the back of that if I every make something out of it. But I decided to quickly browse through my employment contract, and came across a few clauses that may stop me from even doing that.

If so, what steps should I take that could remove this clause from my contract?

```
Outside interests

6.1 Whilst employed by the Company, you will not:

(a) be an employee of, or be engaged in any other capacity by, any company or organisation other
than the Company, unless authorised in writing by the Company;

(b) be involved in any capacity in providing services directly or indirectly to any other Person in
respect of any business which is similar to or which does or might reasonably be expected to
compete or conflict with any aspect of the business of the Company or any Group Company or
which may otherwise affect the proper and efficient performance of your duties;

(c) be entitled to receive or obtain directly or indirectly any discount, rebate, commission or other
benefit in respect of any business transacted (whether or not by you) by or on behalf of the
Company or any Group Company. This prohibition also extends to your Immediate Relatives. If
you, any of your Immediate Relatives or any company or business entity in which either you or
they are interested directly or indirectly obtain any such discount, rebate, commission or other
benefit, you will immediately account to the Company or any Group Company for the amount
received or the value of benefit obtained;

(d) make contact or communicate with any member of the press or media or anyone so connected
on behalf of the Company or any Group Company, or publish any articles or letters or post any
content on any Social Media platform on behalf of the Company or any Group Company other
than as required for the proper purposes of carrying out your duties.
6.2 Nothing in this Agreement will prevent you from holding beneficially by way of bona fide personal
investment up to 1% of any shares or securities in any company.


Intellectual property

6.4 Any discovery, model, concept, idea, know-how, method, database, computer programme or software
(including related preparations and design materials), invention, improvement in procedure, trade mark,
trade name, design, copyright and all similar rights or get-up made, discovered or created by you during
your employment (whether alone or with others and whether or not in the course of your employment) in
connection with or relating to the business of the Company or any Group Company or capable of being
used or adapted for use in it shall belong to and be the absolute property of the Company. If required to
do so by the Company (whether during or after the termination of your employment), you will at the
expense of the Company promptly execute all instruments and do all things necessary to vest ownership
of all other rights, title and interests (including any registered rights in the same) in such discovery, model,
concept, idea, know-how, method, database, computer programme or software (including related
preparations and design materials), invention, improvement in procedure, trade mark, trade name, design,
copyright and all similar rights or get-up in the Company (or its nominee) absolutely and as sole beneficial
owner. By signing this Agreement, you hereby irrevocably waive all your rights pursuant to sections 77 to
83 inclusive of the Copyright Designs and Patents Act 1988 (and any statutory amendment to it).

6.5 You hereby irrevocably appoint the Company to be your attorney to execute and do any such instrument
or thing and generally to use your name for the purpose of giving the Company or its nominee the full
benefit of clause 6.4 of this Agreement. A certificate in writing, signed by any director or the secretary of
the Company, that any instrument or act falls within the authority conferred by this Agreement shall be
conclusive evidence that such is the case so far as any third party is concerned.
```

Comment: Would your new buisness be in the same field as the company you currently work for?

Comment: Changing employment contracts is usually done only before starting employment. Any time after that, you have no leverage. They have no reason to change. If you want to do freelance work, you will need to quit first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If so, what steps should I take that could remove this clause from my
> contract?

You could try to get permission in writing to do whatever it is you wish to do, as allowed in your contract.

You could ask that this clause be removed from your contract. But realistically, if you would be competing with them, why would your company want to let that happen?

Your best bet would be to leave this company and either work for yourself or  for a company that doesn't require such a clause. You might want to put together a solid plan first.